# How to make a Github repo depend on a particular release from another repo?

Tags: git, github, dependency-management, github-release

I have two repos on Github: a database repo and an API repo. These repos must stay separate, however one should depend on the other:

The database repo contains .sql files (tables, test data, sprocs, ...), documentation files, build and release scripts. I use the release script to create an asset file attached to a particular versioned github release containing only the .sql files. The documentation files can grow quite big, so these are not included in the releases. They're instead displayed through the repo's Wiki.

The API repo has unit tests which depend on a database instance created with the .sql files in the database repo. The unit tests are run by Travis CI as well as developers (pytest).

Currently I keep the same .sql files in both repos. However, going forward I would like to avoid this "double bookkeeping". I'd like to keep the .sql files only in the database repo, and then let the API repo "depend" on the versioned releases from the database repo.

Is there a 'best-practice' solution to this kind of problem?

Comment: submodules, perhaps?

Comment: Hi @eftshift0 - maybe, but I don't think git submodules support the use of 'assets' attached to github releases? My understanding was that they will only work with entire repos. Still, it's a possibility. Maybe it's not the end of the world if that documentation gets downloaded along with the .sql, even if it's unnecessary.

Comment: Well.... i hadn't understood the last part of your flow. Perhaps yyou could create release files on the DB project and set up your other project (say, with a script to wrap the whole thing to make it automagical or something more elaborate like maven, gradle or such) to use those release files from the other project.